# How to prove two partial different equations are dual

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, poincare-duality

I have  $m(t, x)$ and $n(t, x)$, where $t \geq 0$ is the time variable and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is the space variable. I also have a speed $x \mapsto v(x)$. We consider the following models:
$$
\frac{\partial m}{\partial t}(t, x)+v(x) \frac{\partial m}{\partial x}(t, x)=0, \quad \frac{\partial n}{\partial t}(t, x)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[v(x) n(t, x)]=0
$$
Actually, with the initial condition, i can find an explicit formula for $m$ and $n$. But, i also have a task which is "Prove these two partial differential equations are dual". I don't know how to do it. I try to find the definition of two dual partial differential equations on the Internet but i don't receive a result.
Can you help me to solve this problem. This is the first time i have had a chance to study this field. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you have to use that by integration by parts
$$
\iint n\, (\partial_tm + v\partial_xm) = \iint -(\partial_t n + \partial_x(vn)) \, m
$$
so the operators defining the equations are (formally) adjoint of each other (at least if $m$ and $n$ vanish at the boundaries)

Comment: @LL3.14 thanks to your guide, i can solve this problem ^^.